# Breeze with Knockout computed value is not defined

Tags: knockout.js, breeze

I'm having trouble creating computed values in Breeze and binding to them with Knockout.

I'm working with the NoDb sample project, which can be download [here](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/download) and [Extending Entities](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/extending-entities) article in the Breeze documentation has been my main source of information.

In the todo.datacontext.js file, I have made the following changes: (I've included the first and last lines to give guidance as to where exactly I've placed the code)

```
...
configureManagerToSaveModifiedItemImmediately();

metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor('TodoItem', function () { }, todoItemInitializer);

function todoItemInitializer(todoItem) {
    todoItem.participantName = ko.computed(function () {
        return 'John' + ' ' + 'Smith';
    });
};

var datacontext = {
...
```

And in Index.html, I added:

```
...
<ul data-bind="foreach: todos">
   <li>
       <p data-bind="text: participantName" />
       <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: isDone" />
...
```

However, I'm getting this error:

> Error retrieving todo lists: Unable to parse bindings. Message:
>   ReferenceError: participantName is not defined; Bindings value: text:
>   participantName

I've also noticed, if I execute this:

```
metadataStore.getEntityType('TodoItem');
```

It's telling me that such a type doesn't exist, even though I'm registering it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Digging deeper in to the documentation and the sample project, I've figured out that if the server is NOT providing any metadata than it must be manually created and registered in the client. See todo.model.js. Below is the most relevant part of the code:

```
var et = new EntityType({
            shortName: "TodoItem",
            namespace: "NoDb.Models",
            autoGeneratedKeyType: AutoGeneratedKeyType.Identity
        });

...

store.addEntityType(et);
store.registerEntityTypeCtor("TodoItem", null, todoItemInitializer);
```

Then the initializer works as expected and ko.computed values are recognized properly. Of course this puts you down a path of having to declare every single property you're going to use. Regular operations and bindings work without any of this code present.

Comment: Yes, Doguhan, the Breeze client requires metadata on the client in order to materialize entities from queries and serialize them during saves. The easiest approach to acquiring metadata is to generate it from the server. But you've got to get it from somewhere. Why are you unable to get it from the server in your case? FWIW, we're working on ways to generate metadata on the server other than from EF or OData sources.

Comment: @Ward I'd be very interested in a way to generate the metadata from POCO objects decorated with attributes. Our Data Access Layer is behind a Repository and any notion of EF is abstracted away by the code. Similarly the entities themselves are mapped from layer to layer. So the Web project has it's own model classes. This is where I found the NoDB sample to be very helpful. I can load the data from our repository and pass it on. I was very excited at first, when regular bindings worked without defining the full model. But that didn't last long.

Comment: Any chance that you can create a "metadata service" on your server? I'm thinking that you set up your POCOS as if they were exposed through Code First EF. You even roll a DbContext. Now this DbContext won't every be used for data operations. It exists solely to be passed to an `EFContextProvider<>` which itself is only used to return metadata about the model. By burying this in a "MetadataService" you can ensure that no one misuses it. Does this make sense? I know it's a workaround (hack) until we have a better answer.

Comment: @Ward I've implemented a MetadataService that adequately hides the DbContext and the EFContextProvider - I'll share my code eventually, but outside of a test project I couldn't get it to work. Sounds like there's an incompatibility with EF 6 (complains about ObjectContext not being found) and getting a weird error with EF 5 (a server was not found SqlException) - any ideas?

Comment: @Ward hm so I've narrowed the EF5 issue to a difference between running on IIS vs IIS Express (which works in my test project)?

Comment: The Breeze .NET components do NOT work with EF6. EF6 is not released. You might be able to make it work but we haven't bothered yet.

Comment: @Ward So DbContext still tries to have an mdf file behind the scenes to extract the metadata, which is problematic in several ways. Do you know if there is a way to create a DbContext without a db behind it?