# Breeze is not materializing entity

Tags: breeze

I'm working with a NoDb solution, I generate metadata of my POCO model using a command line tool I've created following the conversation that took place here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14904913/178620

Even with this metadata, I'm finding that Breeze is not *materializing* entities loaded with a simple query. As a result, `typeInitializers` are not executed and entity properties are not observables.

I know that my setup and metadata is correct, because `ko.computed` properties I've defined on the `typeInitializer` function worked before. Let me explain what changed!

Previously, due to our use of AutoMapper I had to avoid `IQueryable`, which led me to use jQuery gets to load my entities one by one. This way the entities wouldn't be materialized, so I've publicly exposed the `mergeEntity` function in `entityManager` to do this manually and voila (an understatement) things worked.

Since then, we have implemented a cross-cutting model and eliminated AutoMapper, now I can use `IQueryable` again, and thus Breeze queries. However, I'm stumped as to why my entities aren't working as intended!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the entityTypes returned by the yourEntityManager.metadataStore.getEntityTypes() method and compare this to the entity type names embedded in the json returned by the server.

The $type property on each entity in the json results is used to locate the corresponding 'entityType' in the metadataStore. My guess is either that the type names are different now or that you are missing a [BreezeController] attribute on your ApiController.  This attribute insures that the correct JSON.NET serialization settings are used.

Comment: Right on the money, after looking at the $type, I noticed the types had a DynamicProxy namespace, after disabling EF proxy creation with: DbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false; it started working.

Comment: Excellent! and thx for posting back.  I'll try to get something added to our docs for this situation.

Comment: Np. I'm having a similar issue with related collections. I checked the JSON payload and the data is there, type information looks correct. However the children collection is materialized as Object[0]. Any ideas?

Comment: So let's suppose I have entity A, which contains ICollection<B> and Property C, when I observe entity A in Chrome Console I see something like:Object {entityAspect: ctor, C: function, Id: function, …}
C: function dependentObservable() {
Bs: Object[0] - even though the JSON data includes an array B objects